# ¿Cómo mostrar el id de sesión de php con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php

Estoy realizando una pagina web donde en mi archivo index.php ejecuto cada cierto tiempo una función JS y esta función trae datos de un archivo php llamado closeuser.php, en este caso es el id de sesion.

Ejemplo: si imprimo el id de sesión directamente desde el archivo index, me muestra en pantalla el id de sesión o con include y el nombre del archivo si me muestra lo que tiene el archivo closeuser.php, como se muestra en el siguiente código.

Archivo index.php:

```
    <?php 
//session_start();
require_once 'Connections/swag.php';

    $ses = session_id();
    echo $ses;  
    
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head> 
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="imgs/icon/favicon.ico">
        <title>index</title>
        <link href="font-awesome/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
     
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <?php include("closeuser.php"); ?>
    
    
    
    <script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="js/utiles.js"></script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Archivo closeuser.php:

```
<?php

echo "a2";
 $a = session_id();
echo $a;


?>
```

Me imprime correctamente, pero si la realizo con una función de js, como en el siguiente código, no me muestra nada, me muestra una cadena vacía en la consola, entonces no se por que es el problema :

```
    $(function() { 
    cron(); // Lanzo cron la primera vez
    function cron() {
         $.ajax({
          method: "POST",
          url: "closeuser.php", 
          })
        .done(function(msg) {
            console.log(msg)
         
        });
    }
    setInterval(function() {
        cron();
    }, 10000); // cada 10 segundos
});
```

Alguna idea por que me manda la cadena vacía? si imprimo en el archivo closeuser.php otra cadena, por ejemplo echo "a1"; si me muestra pero el id de sesión no.

Comment: ¿Dónde inicias la sesión?